# Best Open source projects in Erlang/OTP for learning

Tags: open-source, erlang

I am new to Erlang and wondering what the best open source projects are out there with good documentation. I completed reading both the books Erlang Programming (Francesco) and Programming Erlang (Joe). From what I can see ErlyWeb (Yariv's web framework) and Mochiweb seems to have good documentation. Given my basic knowledge, are there any  projects with good documentation where I can dive in and understand the code. Any tips/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282205/what-are-the-best-open-source-erlang-projects-files-for-a-novice-to-read

Comment: Thanks Zed! CouchDB looks like a cool project but the source code documentation is almost non-existing. Any suggestions on YAWS, ejabbered or RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMq project is very instructional for learning erlang.

Answer (score 1):

I take inspiration from [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) and [YAWS](http://yaws.hyber.org/) myself.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd, YAWS, CouchDB, RabbitMQ, all are awesome! But can a single person (ambitious and quick learner) dig deep and understand the guts of the system written by master craftsmen.